# Prettier + ESLint + Turborepo issue

Tags: eslint, lint, prettier, turborepo

We're adding Turborepo to our existing project since we want to add one more app. Right now we have an issue with ESLint and Prettier. In our pipeline (GitHub Actions) linting fails with the message:

```
TypeError: prettier.resolveConfig.sync is not a function
  Occurred while linting /home/runner/work/our_turborepo_root/apps/our_app_1/.eslintrc.js:1
  Rule: "prettier/prettier"
      at Program (/home/runner/work/our_turborepo_root/our_app_1/node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier.js:138:40)
```

Here are some relevant files:

**/package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "lint": "turbo run lint",
  "lint:tsc": "turbo run lint:tsc",
  "eslint:ci": "turbo run eslint:ci --filter='./apps/*' --",
  "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\"",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "prettier": "3.0.3"
},
...
```

**/apps/ourApp1/package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "eslint:ci": "npm run lint:ts",
  "lint": "npm-run-all lint:*",
  "lint:ts": "eslint . --ext .jsx,.js,.ts,.tsx --max-warnings 1",
  "lint:tsc": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.json --noEmit && tsc --project ./tsconfig.server.json --noEmit",
  "prettier": "run-p prettier:*",
  "prettier:json": "prettier --write \"**/*.*(json)\"",
  "prettier:scripts": "prettier --write \"**/*.*(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\"",
  "prettier:styles": "prettier --write \"**/*.*(css|scss)\"",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-shared": "*"
},
"overrides": {
  "eslint-config-shared": {
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.0.0"
  }
}
...
```

**/apps/ourApp1/.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['eslint-config-shared'],
};
```

**/packages/eslint-config-shared/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:@next/next/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': 'off',
    'import/named': 'off',
    'jest/expect-expect': [
      'error',
      {
        assertFunctionNames: [
          'expect',
          'expectValidationError',
          'expectNoValidationError',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.js'],
      rules: {
        'require-await': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
      },
    },
    {
      files: ['e2e/**/*.ts'],
      rules: {
        'jest/no-done-callback': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

However, when I run `turbo run lint` locally, it ends successfully. What could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['shared'],
};
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?